# Checking if QBool is available in Qt

Tags: c++, qt4, qt5

Qt4 had QBool that is not available in Qt5 (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/sourcebreaks.html). Does anyone have a clue how to check if QBool is available in curret compilation?

CHecking Qt version should be enough. Is there possibility / way to check Qt's version like VC++'s `_MSC_VER` where we can check VC++ version and choose what to compile by pre-processors

Both Qt4 and Qt5 define QT_CORE_LIB (when `QT += core` set in project file)

Thanks

Comment: it's removed with a reason. Just don't use it

Comment: @BJ good point, but I need to keep supporting Qt4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [QT_VERSION](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#QT_VERSION) macro.

Comment: And more importantly, [`QT_VERSION_CHECK`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#QT_VERSION_CHECK).